# How to copy files in a folder to build?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I have several images in the `icons` folder:

[image]

and would like to copy all `png` files to `build` folder. 
I've tried:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  {
    from: "src/manifest.json",
    transform: function(content, path) {
      // generates the manifest file using the package.json informations
      return Buffer.from(
        JSON.stringify({
          description: process.env.npm_package_description,
          version: process.env.npm_package_version,
          ...JSON.parse(content.toString())
        })
      );
    }
  },
  { from: "icons", to: "./"}
]),
```

But it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

The content of the config file:

```
var webpack = require("webpack"),
    path = require("path"),
    fileSystem = require("fs"),
    env = require("./utils/env"),
    CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin").CleanWebpackPlugin,
    CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin"),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin"),
    WriteFilePlugin = require("write-file-webpack-plugin");

// load the secrets
var alias = {};

var secretsPath = path.join(__dirname, ("secrets." + env.NODE_ENV + ".js"));

var fileExtensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "eot", "otf", "svg", "ttf", "woff", "woff2"];

if (fileSystem.existsSync(secretsPath)) {
  alias["secrets"] = secretsPath;
}

var options = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || "development",
  entry: {
    popup: path.join(__dirname, "src", "js", "popup.js"),
    options: path.join(__dirname, "src", "js", "options.js"),
    background: path.join(__dirname, "src", "js", "background.js")
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: new RegExp('.(' + fileExtensions.join('|') + ')$'),
        loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "html-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: alias
  },
  plugins: [
    // clean the build folder
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    // expose and write the allowed env vars on the compiled bundle
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(["NODE_ENV"]),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: "src/manifest.json",
      transform: function (content, path) {
        // generates the manifest file using the package.json informations
        return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({
          description: process.env.npm_package_description,
          version: process.env.npm_package_version,
          ...JSON.parse(content.toString())
        }))
      }
    },
    { from: "icons", to: "./"}
    ]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "src", "popup.html"),
      filename: "popup.html",
      chunks: ["popup"]
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "src", "options.html"),
      filename: "options.html",
      chunks: ["options"]
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "src", "background.html"),
      filename: "background.html",
      chunks: ["background"]
    }),
    new WriteFilePlugin()
  ]
};

if (env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  options.devtool = "cheap-module-eval-source-map";
}

module.exports = options;
```

Comment: I usually just use an npm srcipt to call copy via the command line. eg. `"copy_files": "cp ./src/icons ./build/icons"`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file-loader should work for your use-case, instead of trying the `CopyWebpackPlugin`.

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'build/[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/

Updated:

Try this code-sandbox, works for me with some minor tweaks:

https://codesandbox.io/s/2rgs4

Here's the build output I'm getting with your config above:

[image]

Comment: I would like to copy every time the files in the icons folder, even when I do not include those files in javascript and that is also the reason, why I choose the copy plugin.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? It seems to be working for me.